# State space with lasso

Tags: r, lasso, state-space-models, high-dimensional

Is it possible to incorporate lasso variable selection in the high dimensional state space model. If yes, is there any code or package available in R

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question!

There are 2 packages in R (to my knowledge) that allow you to use LASSO variable selection.

Package 1: `glmnet`

Package 2: `lars`

**How to use it?**

1. `glmnet` function

General: `glmnet(x, y, family=c("gaussian","binomial","poisson","multinomial","cox","mgaussian"),
    weights, offset=NULL, alpha = 1, nlambda = 100,
    lambda.min.ratio = ifelse(nobs))`

Your case: `x` is an input matrix, `y` is a response, `alpha = 1` means it is using LASSO method. If you set `alpha = 0` it will use Ridge Regularization method.

2. `lars` function

General: `lars(x, y, type = c("lasso", "lar", "forward.stagewise", "stepwise"),  trace = FALSE, normalize = TRUE, intercept = TRUE, Gram, eps = .Machine$double.eps, max.steps, use.Gram = TRUE)`

Your case: `lars(x, y, type = lasso)` where `x` is a matrix of predictors, and `y` is a response.

Comment: Welcome to our site.  The interest in this question is not in the code request, but in incorporating Lasso in a high-dimensional state-space model.  How would you propose doing that?

Comment: I am looking to apply lasso in the state space model

Comment: I want to use it for the state-space estimation ...how can I use this

Answer (score 0):

I give Maybe an over simplified example of a state space model:

You could for example model the transition probabilities

$$p(s’|s)=N(\beta s, \sigma^2)$$

However, when fitting this model, you could potentially put a lasso norm on $\beta$ if $s$ is high dimensional.

So you have some objective with least squares and a penalty.